# Uploading camera image to server using phonegap/cordova and access the data returned by server

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phone gap/cordova and PHP. I created a phone gap/cordova application to upload camera taken image to server.The server uniquely renames the image according to some timestamp code and it has to return that image name back to the app.I have pretty well uploaded the image but I need to retrieve back that image name data echoed back by the server.On success upload, when I tried to alert the data that is returned back by the server, it is alerting [object object].I need to retrieve the value.How can it be possible.My code at the client side is given below.

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function clearCache() {
navigator.camera.cleanup();
}

var retries = 0;
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
var win = function (r) {
    clearCache();
    retries = 0;
    alert('Done! message returned back is '+r);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    if (retries == 0) {
        retries ++
        setTimeout(function() {
            onCapturePhoto(fileURI)
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        retries = 0;
        clearCache();
        alert('Ups. Something wrong happens!');
    }
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

var params=new param();
param.client_device_id=device.uuid;

options.params = params; // if we need to send parameters to the server   request
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://host/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
}

function capturePhoto() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
});
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

The code for the upload.php is given below

```
<?php

if (!file_exists($_POST["client_device_id"])) {
    mkdir($_POST["client_device_id"], 0777, true);
}




 $date = new DateTime();
 $timeStamp=$date->getTimestamp() -1435930688;


move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'f:\\xampp\\htdocs\\FileUpload\\'.$_POST["client_device_id"]."\\".$timeStamp.'.jpg');
echo $timeStamp.".jpg";
?>
```

The problem is that after successful upload in the device it is alerting 'Done! message returned back is [object object]'.I need to get the value.Please help me on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.Just want to share with you all.I used alert(JSON.stringify(r)).Now I know the format of the returned json object .Knowing that I have easily printed out the image name.**r.response** helped me retrieve the generated image name.